# Java android webview with a dynamic URL

Tags: java, android, webview

Good afternoon,

I am quite new to the android development, so please excuse me if my question sounds stupid.

I have created a first layout "main" which consists of a textbox and and a button. The goal of the button is to launch the second layout containing the webview.

What I would like is that when I click on the button, the layout passes the value of the text box (which contains the URL as parameter) to the second layout instead of having a hard-coded URL)

I have been googling, searching for quite a while but so far, not very successful in my searches. Any idea?

Many thanks in advance for your kind help.

// Contents of 'laurent/ch/domoos/MainActivity.java' :

```
package laurent.ch.domoos;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


private Button button;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final Context context = this;

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);



    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonUrl);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, WebViewActivity.class);

            startActivity(intent);
        }

    });

}

}
```

// Contents of laurent/ch/domoos/WebViewActivity.java' :

```
package laurent.ch.domoos;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class WebViewActivity extends Activity  {

String myUrl = "http://192.168.X.YY/Domoos/";
String myUrl2 = "";
private WebView webView;

public void defineURL(String pUrl) {
   this.myUrl2 = pUrl;
}

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {



    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   /* setContentView(R.layout.webview);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl(myUrl);
*/
    setContentView(R.layout.webview);

    //webview use to call own site
    webView =(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView .getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView .getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl(myUrl);

}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create object of your `EditText` like you made it for `Button`
2. Pass `EditText` value in `Intent`

   ```
   intent.putExtra("url",edt.getText().toString());
   ```
3. Access this value in your `WebviewActivity` onCreate()

   ```
   String url=getIntent().getStringExtra("url");
   ```
4. Load this url in your `WebView`.

   ```
   webView.loadUrl(url);
   ```